# Nested For Loop in an html table inside a jinja template

Tags: html, for-loop, jinja2, nested-loops

I am trying to refactor this in order to display 1 table with *header* for headers of the table and *value* as a corresponding cell value under each *header*, however, due to the usage of a nested loop I get multiple tables of one col each listed in a vertical order. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

```
{% for header in aValueKeys%}
 <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>{{ header }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> 
   {% for value in aValues[header] %}
    <tr>
     <td>{{ value }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
 </table> 
{% endfor %}
```

values are being used like so:

```
message = template.render(iD=a_message.iD, aValueKeys=a_message.valueKeys,
                                aValues=a_message.values, aType=a_message.aType,
                                sentence=a_message.sentence)
```

This renders two tables, however, I need it to be in one table. How do I achieve this although there is a nested loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should surround only blocks that need repeating with a `for` loop:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
     {% for header in aValueKeys %}
     <th>{{ header }}</th>
     {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> 
    <tr>
     {% for value in aValues %}
     <td>{{ value }}</td>
     {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this, unfortunately I only get the headers and no values populated from the second loop. :( Any idea why that would be?

Comment: You're using `aValues` as if it were a dict in your question, but I guess it is really a list, in which case you can just iterate over it like my updated answer.